# How do I convert from cartesian ECEF coordinates to RA and Dec as seen from a specific earth location?

Tags: python, gps, astropy, astronomy, skyfield

I have the x,y,z positions of a gps satellite from its precise ephemerides and I am not sure how I can convert from these cartesian ECEF coordinates (WGS-84 G2139 IERS2010 frame specifically) to RA and Dec as seen from a specific earth location using something like astropy or skyfield?

I am not really sure what to try.

Comment: Calculate observer ECEF, do the difference and transform in polar coordinates (and adapt angles), if you assume spherical Earth. Use libraries if you need precise numbers (ellipsoid, and using *correctly* floating point not to lose precision)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.